# PHP Pattern to validate URL in English and persian(Farsi)

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

I have a pattern that checks the given url is correct or not and this is working perfectly fine in English, but when I give it Farsi characters it returns false because of invalid URL.

The code work with some URLs with mixed Farsi characters but it does not work with others! Where can I make a change or what I can add in this pattern so that it can also validate Farsi characters with English?

```
// check if URL is valid format
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w]([-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w])?\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.,\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.,\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.,\/\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/'; 
$isLink = preg_match($pattern, $url); // Returns true if a link
```

Comment: Can you provide an url where it doesn't match? this pattern also matches email and mailto:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **u modifier** for Farsi charaters, but i am not sure about it because you didn't provide any url to check it using **u modifier**

Try like this.

```
// check if URL is valid format
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?
([\d\w]([-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w])?\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.,\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*
(\?(&?([-+_~.,\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.,\/\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/u'; 
$isLink = preg_match($pattern, $url); // Returns true if a link                   ^see
```

Comment: i use u modifier but, u modifier do not work. is there another method for url checking?

Comment: Can you provide an url where it doesn't match?

Comment: for example: when users use booklet to add blog post in website. (blog address: http://todayslinks.blogsky.com/1393/10/12/post-1/%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2, ) you can see booklet picture in post(blue square)